# Django Queryset help, count items associated with item

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am making a web application for an inventory management application using Django. In this web app, storage boxes (with contents) are assigned to people in my database.

I am trying to write a queryset that I could loop over (see my HTML) that would retrieve the total number of boxes assigned to each project e.g. Project: Project Green, Total Boxes: 5. Im having difficulty writing this. I've tried to use _Set for a reverse lookup and the count function but I can't get anything to work.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

I've simplified my code below.

My model:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    box_contents = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True) 
    project_assigned_to = models.ForeignKey('Project', null=True)
    Location = models.OneToOneField('Location', null=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
```

My View:

```
def page(request):
    project_data = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main_app/page.html' , 
    {"project_data":project_data})
```

My HTML:

```
{% for item in project_data %}
<p>Project Name: {{ item.project_name }}</p>
<p>Number of Boxes Assigned: {{ item.Box_set.box_contents.count }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `item.box_set.count`? WHy do you use `box_contents` here in the variable?

Comment: Ah I didn't know that you could count straight from the set! I added the box_contents so that I could use it as a proxy but your method is 10x better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of `Box`es associated with a `Project` with:

```
{{ item.box_set.count }}
```

But this will result in the famous *N+1 problem*: you will make an extra query *per item*. You can avoid this by *annotating* the queryset first with the number of `Box`es, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def page(request):
    project_data = Project.objects.annotate(
        nboxes=Count('box')
    )
    return render(request, 'main_app/page.html' , 
    {"project_data":project_data})
```

Now the `Project`s in this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute named `nboxes`, so then you can render this with:

```
{% for item in project_data %}
<p>Project Name: {{ item.project_name }}</p>
<p>Number of Boxes Assigned: {{ item.nboxes }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked great. I'm now spending some time reading about the N+1 problem.

Comment: @RickDekkard: this blog post might explain it quite well: https://medium.com/@hakibenita/things-you-must-know-about-django-admin-as-your-app-gets-bigger-6be0b0ee9614